# Using the wordpress jetpack json api

Tags: wordpress, api, rest

I've installed the jetpack plugin for my self-hosted wordpress site. The JSON API feature in jetpack allows me to use the rest API (http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/). However i don't understand how to use it.

https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/$site/posts/

How do i find my $site for example?

Any examples that anyone can share?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just replace `$site` with the URL of your site.

https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/www.yoursite.com/posts/

Comment: I Installed JetPack plugin. When I tried to access it says `{"error":"unauthorized","message":"API calls to this blog have been disabled."}` Is there any settings to enable it?

Comment: @DroidLearner link your self-hosted site with WordPress account.

Comment: I am facing the same problem as @droidLearner. I am not able to figure out how make call to my self-hosted blogs api. I have indtalled jetpack and enabled it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did anyone figure this out by chance?

Comment: Does Jetpack contact Wordpress.com, or does it talk to your self-hosted site directly? (I really hope for the latter)

Comment: $site should be the ID of the site, which will be numeric. It can be found by hitting /me/sites (https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1/get/me/sites/) which will yield a list with the IDs. This is the same for Wordpress.com sites and self-hosted.

Comment: Haha, thanks. I spent an hour trying to figure out what `$site` was.

Answer (score 4):

You can replace `$site` with the domain and (if needed) path of your selfhosted Wordpress site that has jetpack installed.

Just try this example where `$site` was replaced with `discover.wordpress.com`

https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/discover.wordpress.com/posts/

If you get the error: `{"error":"unauthorized","message":"API calls to this blog have been disabled."}` with your own site make sure that you enabled the json api in the `general` section of your jetpack plugin settings.

[image: enable json api for jetpack]

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question but maybe others coming across this post, as I did, would want to know how to possible fix the problem.

In my case I am:

- Using Jetpack
- Self-hosted site

I was receiving the error:

{"error":"unauthorized","message":"API calls to this blog have been disabled."}

In order to fix it:

- Disconnect the Jetpack plugin
- Reconnect again.

Fixed the issue!